# Issues installing pywin32

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

```
pip install pywin32
```

When I try the above code, I get the following error in Jupyter Notebook.

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32
>
> Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

Comment: What version of Python are you running? Are you able to get the Python REPL from the command prompt or Powershell? I'd look there first.

Comment: '3.9.13 (main, Aug 25 2022, 18:29:29) \n[Clang 12.0.0 ]' is my python version. ie 3.9.13. what is python REPL?

Comment: REPL = Read, Eval, Print Loop.
Can you get to python command line by just typing `python` in your command prompt?

Comment: It doesn't work on a Mac.

Comment: pywin32 is not supported on mac. Its windows only.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Jupyter, write it in CMD. In CMD, chase the exact directory of pip by writing cd and then the location of pip.

This might work.